# Can I call load_dotenv twice?

Tags: python, auth0

Can I call `load_dotenv` twice in a single run of a script?

I want to connect to two Auth0 tenants at the same time.

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import environ as env
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from auth0.v3.authentication import GetToken
from auth0.v3.management import Auth0
from auth0.v3.exceptions import Auth0Error

import constants


def connect_to_auth0(environment):
    env_file = '.env.' + environment
    env_path = Path('.') / env_file
    load_dotenv(env_path)
    auth0_client_id = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID]
    auth0_client_secret = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET]
    auth0_domain = env[constants.AUTH0_DOMAIN]
    mgmt_api_url = 'https://'+auth0_domain+'/api/v2/'

    get_token = GetToken(auth0_domain)
    token = get_token.client_credentials(auth0_client_id,
                                         auth0_client_secret,
                                         mgmt_api_url)
    mgmt_api_token = token['access_token']
    return Auth0(auth0_domain, mgmt_api_token)


def main():
    tenant_1 = connect_to_auth0('tenant_1')
    tenant_2 = connect_to_auth0('tenant_2')
```

and there's a `.env.tenant_1` and `.env.tenant_2` with appropriate parameters for each tenant. `tenant_1` and `tenant_2` are different python objects, but both are referencing tenant 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `dotenv_values` rather than `load_dotenv`, so that you get back a `dict` rather than updating the environment. (I assume your otherwise undefined global `env` comes from something like `from os import environ as env`?)

```
def connect_to_auth0(environment):
    env_file = '.env.' + environment
    env_path = Path('.') / env_file
    env = dotenv_values(env_path)
    auth0_client_id = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID]
    auth0_client_secret = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET]
    auth0_domain = env[constants.AUTH0_DOMAIN]
    mgmt_api_url = 'https://'+auth0_domain+'/api/v2/'

    get_token = GetToken(auth0_domain)
    token = get_token.client_credentials(auth0_client_id,
                                         auth0_client_secret,
                                         mgmt_api_url)
    mgmt_api_token = token['access_token']
    return Auth0(auth0_domain, mgmt_api_token)
```

Comment: That's correct re: global `env`. I'll have a look at `dotenv_values`.